# How to find out if the result of two separate queries match?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to find out if the result of the two queries match. We can write queries in different shapes, but is there a way to find out that they do match?
for example the below queries don't match, but is there any function that returns false if they don't? the queries are as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM orders JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM customers WHERE state IN ('OH', 'NY', 'OR')
) AS ord USING (customerid)
ORDER BY orderid
```

and

```
SELECT c.firstname, c.lastname, o.orderid 
FROM orders AS o, (
    SELECT customerid, state, firstname, lastname
    FROM customers
) AS c
WHERE  o.customerid = c.customerid AND 
c.state IN ('NY', 'OH', 'OR')
ORDER BY o.orderid;
```

I'm using Postgresql and I need to know if these queries are identical in the results

Comment: Why are you using commas in the `FROM` clause?  The queries are not identical, because they select different columns.

Comment: Yes, but in situations where we can write the same query in different ways is there a solution to know the results are the same? @gordon-linoff

Comment: I suggest using store procedure to get result of each line and compare or if result must exact same use minus and get diff of each query

Answer (score 1):

Use the `EXISTS` operator combined with full outer join.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM (QUERY1) a NATURAL FULL
      JOIN (QUERY2)
    ) THEN 'different'
    ELSE 'same'
  END AS result;
```

Replace `QUERY1` and `QUERY2` with those select statements.

[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72641/checking-whether-two-tables-have-identical-content-in-postgresql)